# Typescript, I want define a function to set attributes dynamically

Tags: typescript

```js
export interface DemoAttr<T> {
    attr: Demo<T>
    a: boolean
    b: string
}

export class Demo<T> implements DemoAttr<T>{
    attr = {} as Demo<T>
    a = false
    b = ''
    
    setAttr(key: keyof DemoAttr<T>, value: DemoAttr<T>[keyof DemoAttr<T>]) {
        // how to fix it? and why?
        // I use `any` to replace the value type is not work either
        this.attr[key] = value
    }

}
```

I just wonder to know what reason causes this error, any why even use `any` can not fix it either?

and if I remove the `b` attribute and use `any` as `value` type then it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix it, you need to use type inference on function arguments:

```js
export interface DemoAttr<T> {
  attr: Demo<T>
  a: boolean
  b: string
}

export class Demo<T> implements DemoAttr<T>{
  attr = new Demo<T>()
  a = false
  b = ''

  setAttr<Key extends keyof Demo<T>>(key: Key, value: Demo<T>[Key]) {
    this.attr[key] = value
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wEBbkN)

More about this topic you van find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments).

As you might have noticed, I have provided generic `Key` and applied a constraint `Key extends keyof Demo<T>`. It means that `Key` should be a subtype of `Demo<T>` keys/props. But you probably aware of that, because you were close. However, using

```js
setAttr(key: keyof DemoAttr<T>, value: DemoAttr<T>[keyof DemoAttr<T>])
```

without generic parameter is not safe, because there is no correlation between `key` and `value`. In other words, `key` might be an `a` prop and `value` might be a `string`. Both of them are valid but in the same moment it is not type safe.

You also have used `DemoAttr<T>` as a dependent type for arguments, which is not correct because `attr` is in fact a `Demo` type and not `DemoAttr`. `attr` is a `Demo` instance, hence you can't use `DemoAttr` interface for that purpose